# How to make button Click Event handler work?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, modal-dialog

I am linking a gridView Link Button to a modal popup as below:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Analyze">
                                 <ItemTemplate>
                                       <asp:LinkButton Text="Analyze" ID="lnkView" runat="server" ControlStyle-Font-Underline="true"  />
                                 </ItemTemplate>
                             </asp:TemplateField>
```

The code for the modal popup is as below:

```
 <div id="dialog" style="display: none">
            <div style="text-align:center">
                 <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text="Result Id:" />
                <asp:TextBox ID="tb" runat="server" Value="102" />
            </div>
            <br />
            <div>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Bug Id:" />
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="bugidtb" Value="Enter Bug Id:"/>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div>
                <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text="Bug DB:" />
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" Width="250px" ID="Bugdb" >
                    <asp:ListItem>OneBug</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Jira</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
            <br/><br/>
            <asp:Button runat="server" Text="OK" OnClick="ModalOK_Click"/>
            <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="test" Text="hello world" />

        </div>


      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/start/jquery-ui.css"
            rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).on("click", "[id*=lnkView]", function () {

                $("#resultId").html($(".ResultId", $(this).closest("tr")).html());
                $("#dialog").dialog({
                    title: "Analyze Result",
                    modal: true
                });
                return false;
            });
        </script>
```

The button click event handler code in the modal isn't getting executed.
I debugged to find out the event handler isn't responding at all.

How do I make it work?

Comment: Try changing the selector as `"input[id$='lnkView']"`

Comment: Accept the answer which helped you so question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Possible issue is your jquery script is unable to find the id thats why event is not firing.

Try using the

```
     '<%=lnkView.ClientID%>'
```

This will work very fast as it will use native `document.getElementById`.

in your selector.
OR
  try using the jquery ends with selector,

```
          input[id$='lnkView']
```

You can also use the `ends with` jquery selector to get the `lnkView` server generated id using `input[id$='lnkView']`. Also However `$("[id$=lnkView]")` will select more than one element, so if you have same id assigned to more than one element and if you would like to traverse all of them then first case will not work properly.

But I would go with the first approach. As server control id generation pattern is something  you dont want to dependent on.

Answer (score 0):

Better Try to call the click Event with in your link button tag itself, because buttons, link buttons, images, etc., placed with in the gridview cannot be identified by the javascript.

```
function Analyse(){

            $("#resultId").html($(".ResultId", $(this).closest("tr")).html());
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                title: "Analyze Result",
                modal: true
            });
            return false;
        }
```

Add Attribute **OnClientClick="Analyse()"** to your link button

Comment: If I do this,when I click the link button the modal appears for a second and then disappears again.

Comment: try OnClientClick="return Analyse()"